# CSS Help with Top Menu Items

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu, stylesheet

I am not sure of how to get this to work, I have a Drop Down Menu that is cross browser compatible and I am trying to have the selected "bread crumb" menus system keep the arrows on the :hover style when I am on child menus. As you can see from the link here:

http://www.seth-duncan.com/Test/TestMenu.html

When I go to child menu items the menu reverts back to the blue arrows, when I need them to keep the hover style white arrows.

Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
background:#A5CF8C url(images/DownArrow.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
```

from 
    `#menu li a.sub:hover` 
to
    `#menu li:hover a.sub`